# Scrolling the android recyclerview inhibits clicking on the screen

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-listview

i have this problem in my android mobile app, i am using kotlin.

In the main of the project I have a list of cards, made through RecyclerView, when the cards are of a greater number than the screen can accommodate, the vertical scrolling is rightly enabled. As soon as I scroll the list vertically, the action is completed, but upon release I can no longer click anywhere within my app. (clicks work outside the app)
This is the HTML of that piece of code:

```
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
     android:id="@+id/itemsswipetorefreshSite"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="0px"
     android:layout_weight="1">
     <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewSite"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/twenty">
     </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

This piece of code is contained in a *CoordinatorLayout* inside which there is a *ConstraintLayout* which in turn has a *LinearLayout* that encloses the list.

The same problem does not occur in other parts of the app, or in other components / fragments I have other lists, made in the exact same way, but under this situation they do not produce this bug.

The log that is produced at the time of the bug (from the beginning of the scrolling) is the following:

> I/HwViewRootImpl: removeInvalidNode all the node in jank list is out of time
> W/HiTouch_PressGestureDetector: Touch pointer move a lot. The moving distance of X is:7.0, limit is:60The moving distance of Y is:61.94568, limit is:60
> D/OverScrollerOptimization: fling time is flingTime = 1.9100340578075632 velocity = 1261
> D/OverScrollerOptimization: fling time is flingTime = 1.9100340578075632 velocity = 1261

but the same is produced, very similar in the other lists for the same action.

Your every help is truly precious, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[SOLVED]**

Maybe it can help someone who is in the same situation as me: I found that in the adapter file of the list in question I found a

```
requireActivity (). window.setFlags (WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE)
```

that it didn't have to be there and every time I touched the list it was activated. Typical problem of a hasty copy and paste.

Answer (score 0):

set `layout_height` to `wrap_content` in both `swipeRefreshlayout` and also in your `recyclerView`

Comment: thanks for your reply but unfortunately this doesn't help with my problem at all